# Showing on mobile truncate text hidden by hover

Tags: html, css, angular, hover

I have a question related due to how to show truncated text on angular app using mobile...

```css
td {
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
td:hover{
    overflow: visible; 
    white-space: normal;
    height:auto;
}
```

[image: how it works on pc]

This is enough to show all truncated text but in **PC**!!! on mobile i know there´s no hover effect but i face this for first time today!, and i want to know if it is possible to make a similar effect on mobile devices, in an angular app of course.

[image]

*On mobile*... What can i say there´s no function, that even no exists!( my cursor is over the textfields but in a screenshot it doesnt appear.

Thank all of you.

**EDITED:**

```html
<tr>
 <td>
   {{vName.get(name.property)}}
  </td>
    <td id="grid" "" *ngFor="let varT of part[0] && somecode; let i = index">
      {{interpolation}}
 </td>
 </tr>
```

so there i want to make by css if it is possible(looks like not), maybe using longpressEvents like our first answer.
So resuming i want in that `td` my text is truncate and when i checked on pc hover works but i want the same for mobiles its important, i have a way to fix it but its another implementation so i prefer to learn "how to make hovers on mobile devices".

Comment: It needs an event to show/hide all text. So you can have an icon for that and toggle it on click or you can use long-press event.

Comment: Are you able to show me a functional live example?? searching around and couldnt find something that works. I´m pretty sure there´s actually a way to do it, may be not on 2015 but nowdays...

Comment: Please update your question and add a working demo, or explain more about your expectation and current behavior

Comment: here you have! @M98, thank you!

Comment: delay one second and show a tooltip with full text when the cell touched

Comment: thank you @raghulselvam that fits perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile hover works like a click event .

When you click it it will trigger the hover in css.

When you click outside it will hover the blur event.

Check this link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_buttons_fade1

If you want to do it in another way like hover type then you can give the user the eye icon and bind it to the touch event. Yes using the touch start and touch end event listeners you can make the td visible bits data when the user keep pressing the eye icon.
Why eye icon because so that user knows that by touching it the contents will be visible

Check this link.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp